# Python - Attempting to end file adress with a \", causes EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, eol

```
import os.path
LicencePlate = input("Plate me Bitch")
savePath = "M:\Python\PlatesOffences\"
print(savePath + LicencePlate)
if os.path.exists(savePath + + LicencePlate + ".txt" ) == True:
    print("FileFound")`
```

The backslash that I need for the file address causes the code to ignore the Quote mark, returning an EOL while scanning string literal error. I have no ide how to fix this.

Comment: Because it escapes the closing quote; double the backslashes.

Comment: \ is used to escape characters inside a string, so the closing quote becomes a literal quote. Use \\.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` is an escape character in string literals. It modifies the behavior of the character that follows. In your case, it modified the meaning of `"` to no longer represent the end of the string.

Try one of these alternatives:

```
savePath = "M:\\Python\\PlatesOffences\\"
savePath = "M:/Python/PlatesOffences/"
```